# Run Api Call Exception Unable to load shared library 'libsecret-1.so.0' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, linux, azure, azure-appservice

We are moving a .net core 3.1 application from a Windows Azure App Service to a Linux Azure App Service.

We have code that does a webapi call to a rest service, using System.Net.Http.HttpClient.

When this call runs we get the error message:

> WepApiClient, Run Api Call Exception Unable to load shared library
> 'libsecret-1.so.0' or one of its dependencies. In order to help
> diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment
> variable: liblibsecret-1.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such
> file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have now fixed this.

When we created the Http client, we read some values from Azure Keyvault. The access to Keyvault was not configured correctly, so that called failed.

After we fixed the connection information and rights to Keyvault it worked.